# Can I charge the 12" macbook with Nintendo switch charger?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, charging

Just wondering if I could charge my 12inch macbook with the type-c adopter that came with the Nintendo switch

https://store.nintendo.co.uk/nintendo-switch-accessory/nintendo-switch-power-adapter/11396099.html

Comment: Even if someone here says it's ok, would you really take the chance on a non-warrantied fry-out of your MB motherboard to use a $25 charger?

Comment: @fsb I agree its risky, but the whole promise of USB-C is inter-compatibility and simplification. I am still deeply confused as to what is appropriate to use with which device. While I have no real need for this it would be good to know

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have tested on the 2015 MacBook 12". Works perfectly. Charges at 15.3V @ 1,9A = 28,7W. The MacBook 12" charger also works on the Switch.

USB-C and recent [USB Power Delivery standards](http://www.usb.org/developers/powerdelivery/) make this a fairly safe bet in terms of cross platform interoperability. As long as the charger or cable aren't knockoff, you should expect reasonable results mixing vendors.

Reasonable is a 15 inch MacBook Pro clearly won't run and charge from a 30 watt adapter (whether Apple or Nintendo), but if powered off, it will slowly and safely charge itself at the rate the connected adapter provides.

Comment: Works fine with my 15" MBP while in use (for dev work) -  at least when it's not being heavily taxed.

Answer (score 2):

Just an important pointer for anyone considering to charge their switch with non nintendo chargers!! Watch out, using the non-nintendo certified chargers have a real chance of completely bricking your device.

The switch charging standard is not completely the same and using a different charger could render your switch useless.

More information:
https://bgr.com/2018/04/06/nintendo-switch-charging-cables-warning-bricked/